# Должны ли результаты "Gradient Boosting" быть разными, если поменять местами признаки

Tags: машинное-обучение, sklearn

Есть набор данных для классификации в "Gradient Boosting".
Если я меняю их местами получается разный результат. Так должно быть?
Если результаты должны быть действительно разными, значит есть смысл попробовать разные последовательности?
Разместил файл с данными здесь [данные](https://dropmefiles.com/3C943).
Последнее значение справа это метки классов(бинарная классификация)

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('dataclass.csv',
                      header=None)

    
    split = 5700
    
    y = df1.iloc[:, 11].values# метки классов
    y  = y.astype('int')
    len_ = len(y)
    
    q = np.ones((len_, 11), dtype=float)
    q[0:len_, 0] = df1.iloc[:, 7].values
    q[0:len_, 1] = df1.iloc[:, 8].values
    q[0:len_, 2] = df1.iloc[:, 9].values
    q[0:len_, 3] = df1.iloc[:, 10].values
    q[0:len_, 4] = df1.iloc[:, 0].values
    q[0:len_, 5] = df1.iloc[:, 5].values
    q[0:len_, 6] = df1.iloc[:, 4].values
    q[0:len_, 7] = df1.iloc[:, 3].values
    q[0:len_, 8] = df1.iloc[:, 2].values
    q[0:len_, 9] = df1.iloc[:, 1].values
    q[0:len_, 10] = df1.iloc[:, 6].values
    q = np.round(q, 5)
    
    X_train = q[:split]
    clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=3, max_features="sqrt", n_estimators=30,
                                         learning_rate=0.01,random_state=0)
    
    clf.fit(X_train, y[:split])
    yALL = clf.predict(q)
    peport = classification_report(y, yALL)
    print(peport)

    y_test = clf.predict(q[split:])
    confmat = confusion_matrix(y[split:], y_test)

   print(confmat)
```

Если запускаю на обучение, то получаются следующие метрики:

```
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support
    
               0       0.61      0.05      0.09      3867
               1       0.51      0.97      0.67      3983
    
        accuracy                           0.52      7850
       macro avg       0.56      0.51      0.38      7850
    weighted avg       0.56      0.52      0.39      7850

[[187 875]
 [172 916]]
```

Делаю следующую очередность признаков:

```
q[0:len_, 0] = df1.iloc[:, 0].values
q[0:len_, 1] = df1.iloc[:, 1].values
q[0:len_, 2] = df1.iloc[:, 2].values
q[0:len_, 3] = df1.iloc[:, 3].values
q[0:len_, 4] = df1.iloc[:, 4].values
q[0:len_, 5] = df1.iloc[:, 5].values
q[0:len_, 6] = df1.iloc[:, 6].values
q[0:len_, 7] = df1.iloc[:, 7].values
q[0:len_, 8] = df1.iloc[:, 8].values
q[0:len_, 9] = df1.iloc[:, 9].values
q[0:len_, 10] = df1.iloc[:, 10].values
```

результат получается несколько иной:

```
                  precision    recall  f1-score   support
    
               0       0.63      0.04      0.08      3867
               1       0.51      0.98      0.67      3983
    
        accuracy                           0.52      7850
       macro avg       0.57      0.51      0.38      7850
    weighted avg       0.57      0.52      0.38      7850

[[250 812]
 [222 866]]
```

Comment: А если ничего не менять, а просто несколько раз обучение запустить - результаты одинаковые или разные? В принципе, модель может давать несколько случайный результат даже на одних и тех же данных. Но это всё же зависит от конкретных данных. Сами данные можете показать? Да и код тоже хорошо бы посмотреть.

Comment: Так то вообще порядок следования столбцов с фичами не должен никакой роли играть, если вы, конечно, не обрабатываете разные столбцы разными способами в зависимости от их номера.

Comment: одинаковые в настройках: random_state=0. Данные сейчас не могу показать. Если нужно, то завтра. Данные остаются неизменными обработка их происходит задолго до подачи. Много проверял ошибки не нахожу, но вполне мог где-то что-то не учесть.

Comment: Ну, если `random_state` фиксирован, тогда вообще странно. Надеюсь, данные вы и в `train` и в `test` одинаково ротируете?

Comment: Все-таки попробую сейчас все фичи в файл скинуть. Вы здесь еще в течении 1-1.5 часа будете присутствовать?

Comment: Я допоздна периодически тут тусуюсь

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил сообщение кодом и данными в файле.

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня свои метрики, в них еще больше разница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел немного ваши данные. Могу сделать следующие выводы и замечания.

- вы зря предсказываете на всех данных, надо только на тесте предсказывать по-хорошему, дальше я делаю наблюдения по предсказаниям только на тесте, хотя и предсказание на всех данных даёт в принципе те же результаты
- качество предсказаний вашей модели близко к случайному `0.5` с некоторой погрешностью
- с заданным вами параметром `max_depth=1` модель в 99% случаев предсказывает результат `1`, хотя во входных данных примерно поровну зачений `0` и `1`
- если увеличить глубину деревьев до `max_depth=10`, то модель начинает больше 0 предсказывать (где-то 1/3 `0` на 2/3 `1`), но в целом качество модели всё-равно получается близко к случайному `0.5`
- если поиграться параметром `random_state`, то вы увидите даже бОльший разброс качества, чем при перемешивании колонок, таким образом, наблюдающаяся разница целиком объясняется тем, что модель берёт случайные наборы колонок, какие именно и в каком порядке - зависит как от `random_state`, так и от физического расположения колонок, в общем, можно считать, что **перемешивая колонки, вы просто меняете `random_state`**, вот и всё объяснение разницы в метриках

Изменённый код для более понятного разбиения на трейн/тест и проверки на тесте:

```
X_train, X_test = q[:split],q[split:]
y_train, y_test = y[:split],y[split:]
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(max_depth=1, max_features="sqrt", n_estimators=30,
                                     learning_rate=0.01,random_state=4)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
peport = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print(peport)
```

Comment: У меня свои методы. Обучаю на тест. Но, впрочем, чтобы не раздувать код много чего убрал. А так много чего проверяется на тест и на всех данных. Глубину, как правило беру 3-5. Просто на глубине 1 это видно по этим метрикам. Мои метрики более чувствительные.  Признаки взял не значимые. В действительности есть хорошие, но это не относится к этому вопросу)

Comment: @inquirer Ну, не следует в проверке использовать трейн. Если модель ничему не выучилась, вы это и по тесту поймёте. А если выучилась, то на образцах из трейна будет завышенное качество, которое сдвинет метрику в лучшую сторону чем она есть на самом деле.

Comment: Хорошо объясню) Проверяю на тест, если устраивает, смотрю график баланса в целом. Так как предсказываю финансовые активы акции, валюты и пр.  Кода в раз пять больше, для простоты сделал короче.

Comment: @inquirer В общем, если вы найдёте данные/призаки, на которых разница от перемешивания столбцов будет существенно другой, чем от смены `random_state`, тогда будет иметь смысл говорить о каком-то феномене, пока на этих данных я никакого феномена не наблюдаю, всё объясняется небольшой рандомностью самой модели )

Comment: Хорошо Вас устроит график прироста капитала до перестановки и после? В нем обозначены тестовый и тренировочный участок.

Comment: Сначала попробуйте смену `random_state` )  Если она не даст такого же эффекта, тогда можно дальше что-то рассматривать. Я и сам занимаюсь биржей, в том числе по работе, и считаю по большому счёту всю алгоритмическую торговлю делом случая. Сегодня ваша стратегия работает в прибыль, а завтра в убыток. Или даже так: на исторических данных стратегия работает, а на новых - уже нет.

Comment: Дополнил матрицей признаков код, сделал глубину три. Теперь видна разница. И это на тесте)

Comment: А вы попробуйте другие `random_state`, попробуйте. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... Некоторые варианты получаются совсем другие, чем с `random_state=0`

Comment: Понятно. Вообщем меняя местами создаю своего рода перемешивание, возможно и так. Но, все-таки решил спросить. Цифры в "random_state" это сколько раз данные перемешиваются? Просто в литературе конкретно ничего по этому поводу не нашел. Если так, то 0 что означает?

Comment: Нет, это фактически `random seed`, если вам это о чём-то говорит. Т.е. это некое число, которым инициализируется генератор случайных чисел, который используется моделью, чтобы случайно выбирать фичи и сэмплы из датасета (и таких выборок там далеко не одна, конечно). Ну то есть это просто некое число, которое ничего не значит, кроме того, что если задать одно и то же число, то результат работы модели должен быть одинаковым.